# Does the anticlass principle solve the Burali-Forti problem?

Tags: paradox, foundations-of-mathematics

**Justification of the foundations-of-mathematics tag:** I was reading through a long text on category theory, [*Abstract and Concrete Categories: The Joy of Cats*](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf), and they make much of the class/set distinction, including as a foundational matter, situating this distinction relative to another such notion, that of "conglomerates," and they float the idea that we could go on to talk of "collections":

[image]

So differentiating between sets, proper classes, etc. is a foundational issue in mathematics.

**The Burali-Forti problem:** this arises from postulating that there is a set of all and only ordinals. I will cite an [SEP representation of the problem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradoxes-contemporary-logic/#DiffInvoOrdiCardNumb):

> Burali-Forti, a mathematician of Peano’s school, attempted to prove that the ordinal numbers are not linearly ordered. Assuming by contradiction that the class **ON** of all ordinals could be linearly ordered, he observed that then **ON** itself would be well-ordered and it would possess an ordinal Ω ∈ **ON**. Thus **ON** would be similar (order-isomorphic) to a proper initial segment of itself, the one determined by Ω, contradicting a well-known theorem about well-ordered sets. The result was published in 1897 and, though Burali-Forti’s original aim is impossible to achieve, his argument showed that the collection **ON** is problematic at best (Moore-Garciadiego 1981).

Now the anticlass principle is a restriction on the use of the "all and only" quantifier, which says that there are some intensions such that if there is a set containing all satisfiers of those intensions, then that set contains all satisfiers of all intensions whatsoever. The reason for calling this an "anticlass" principle is that it means that, in the given system, there are no such distinguished entities as **ON** or **CARD** (for "all and only cardinals") or the like; rather, any set large enough to house all ordinals must house all non-ordinals too, etc.

If there were a set with all elements only of **ON**, it would be well-ordered, would then have an ordinal to its name, and so that is how the Burali-Forti problem is posed. However, if the set that houses all those elements has all other elements to its name, too, then it would *not* be well-ordered in the limit, so would not have an ordinal to its name, and there would be no universal ordinal (although we would still be minded to say that the universal set's absolute infinity overshadows all the ordinals that are relatively infinite, then). So does the anticlass principle offer a solution to the Burali-Forti problem, or is it an example of what the SEP article means by saying that "Burali-Forti's original aim is impossible to achieve"?

Comment: Can you provide definitions of classes, sets, conglomerations, and classes, please.

Comment: And quasicategories. product(A, pi) is the product of (A)I in that quasicategory. Why is the pi there? What does it denote?

Comment: A is an object in Class, the quasicategory of all classes. Thus, A is a class. A product of A's is a conglomerate, but frequently fails to be a class. Why?

Comment: Are sets, collections, classes, and conglomerates a complete set of unique things which together resolve foundational problems, or are they just names for an arbitrary sequence of containers, like universes, and could go on infinitely? Do they have any special distinct properties from each other?

Comment: What is a quasi-quasicategory?

Comment: What is the omega ordinal? Is it that if ON is well-ordered, it has a supremum, which is Omega? Thus ON is both of a certain ordinal rank, and yet contains the ordinal of that rank as an element... i actually cant remember why that would be a problem. i mean the reals are order-isomorphic to a proper subset of them. but this would contradict a well known theorem. which one?

Comment: Burali Fortes original aim is impossible to achieve. Why? He showed the converse to be a contradiction, did he not? Also. The takeaway here is that if ON exists, it is not linearly ordered, which sounds strange since we would strongly expected ordinals to be ordered. Correct? So the question is, does it exist in some unexpected, counterintuitive way, or does it simply not exist at all. I think.

Comment: Is the "anticlass principle" your own proposal or is it taken from somewhere? "There are some intensions" (which ones?) and "all satisfiers of all intensions whatsoever" sound rather vague, and the only references I found are in the context of law, not set theory. How is it supposed to interact with the axiom of specification, which is "proclass"? And without specifying "some intensions", it it is too much like "restrict comprehension when it leads to a contradiction" 'principle', which is only a heuristic for finding actual principles.

Comment: @Conifold I don't know that there's an anticlass principle so-called in the literature (though Quine's NF, not his ML, might be of this flavor?), but I have Penelope Maddy's critique of something from Reinhardt in the back of my mind, here (Believing the Axioms II): "This treatment [of the set/class distinction] is neat, so neat that we begin to wonder if these new layers really consist of entities of a new and different type; perhaps we just forgot to finish the iterative hierarchy in the first place."

Comment: As for which intensions: those which in the theory of proper classes are satisfied by the members of those proper classes, e.g. if there were said to be a proper class of inaccessibles otherwise, here we'd say that any collection housing all inaccessibles also houses all accessibles, etc. We could get another multiverse out of this, then (for example, in one universe with class-many measurables, the universal set has all measurables and all other cardinals anyway, etc.).

Comment: @JuliusH. I think the uppercase pi is a product notation. Like often if you write ΠA you mean to multiply all the A's (whatever they are in context). Now my own takeaway here is that there is no **ON** but just some *U* that houses all the ordinals and all the unordered/disorderly sets, too, and this *U* doesn't have an ordinal for all of itself; the surviving residue of **ON** is the ability to plurally quantify over all and only ordinals, where plural quantification doesn't correspond to a specific set of "all and only ordinals" (or "all and only" some other kind of thing).

Comment: Thanks but I meant the small pi. its PI(A, pi).

Comment: @JuliusH. sometimes the lowercase pi is used as a function symbol. Like sometimes instead of *j*: *V* into *V* (for an elementary embedding), you'd write π: *V* into *V*. I don't know why they do that, but I'm guessing that's what is meant here (since the passage talks about "all classes and all functions").

Comment: yes, ive seen it in the context of homotopy theory before, in that way.

Comment: Quasicategories are a synonym for infinity categories. Maybe someone can get ahold of this text where they were [introduced](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0068547). “The idea of higher category theory (at least, higher category theory when higher morphisms are invertible) is that, as opposed to the standard notion of a category, there should be a mapping space (rather than a mapping set) between two objects. This suggests that a higher category should simply be a topologically enriched category.” My guess is small pi represents the “mapping space” for each object in the product.

Comment: “the "all and only" quantifier, which says that there are some intensions such that if there is a set containing all satisfiers of those intensions…” is this precise? Are you introducing a new kind of quantifier? This cant be done with normal “for all”? This sounds like set comprehension.

Comment: Maybe I’ll just ask all these questions as their own posts.

Comment: I think I am missing what kind of set theory the anticlass principle is supposed to supplement and what it is meant to accomplish. It seems that all you are adding is a single new set "of all intensions whatsoever". First, if it is a *set* how does it avoid Russell's paradox? And second, if that is all there is to it then what do we need the principle for? Theories with proper classes already remove the Burali-Forti paradox, and there is little point to policing proper classes. They are there mostly for terminological convenience, one cannot do much with them anyway.

Comment: No need for cats to behold 'differentiating between sets, proper classes is a foundational issue in mathematics', ZF or the G Universe are enough. A conglomerate as dependent product are usually not large enough to be qualified as a class which cannot be a member of any other class. Burali-Forti had no concept of the difference of proper class and set yet so his aim cannot be achieved, but his 'paradox' contradicted a well known theorem that any ordinal is not order-isomorphic to any of its proper initial segments which is derivable from Cantor's theorem. A set cannot house all ordinals...

Comment: @Conifold apparently ([at least in GB](https://jdh.hamkins.org/the-global-choice-principle-in-godel-bernays-set-theory/)), if |ORD| = |CARD| (or if all proper classes are the "same size"), then global choice follows. But I am partial to choiceless sets, e.g. amorphous ones, so I would prefer a system where global choice is not so easily come by. Not having proper classes to compare seems to be a way to get this, if there is only the universal set "up there." As for Russell's paradox, I assume that the separation axiom eventually fails just like GCH or choice in more normal hypotheses.

Comment: Speaking of class and sets likely implies that we are working in a model $V$ of set theory. If that is the case you should add details to what are the "all and only" quantifier as well as "intensions"-- as those do not exist in usual set theory. As is, I think the question should be put on hold and it may be in any case a better fit for the math SE.

Comment: @Johan or we're hopping from universe to universe in the set-theoretic multiverse, so to speak, playing with axioms and logical backgrounds to see if we can find nonstandard solutions to classical problems.

Comment: Maybe. But then you need to clarify what this mean on top of the non-canonical terms used in the question.

Comment: @Johan I have seen the phrase "all and only" often enough in established works of set theory to recognize that it is a specific locution with a specific function therein. Besides the word "anticlass" (which is explained), where are the non-canonical terms in my question?

Comment: Then you should be able to define it for those who never saw it. As well as "intensions". As for the definition of anticlass it is still very vague.

Comment: @Johan "all and only" is too simple for someone not to understand by their own power and knowledge of the given language. "Intensions" is a very common word in technical philosophy. "Anticlass" might be vague but so is the concept of a proper class, or a set, or a conglomerate, or whatever; it's an unavoidable feature of comprehensive foundational work.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean by "intentions", as in "intensional definition". In the context of set theory, those would simply be called formulas. But very honestly, I can't put a meaning on the "all and only" quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will likely be garbage but I hope it can give any others some momentum here.

###### Does the anticlass principle solve the Burali-Forti problem?

Berry defines the "anticlass principle" as `"a restriction on the use of the 'all and only' quantifier, which says that there are some intensions such that if there is a set containing all satisfiers of those intensions, then that set contains all satisfiers of all intensions whatsoever"`.

This seems to indicate that quantifiers are something you can restrict. In order to continue this answer I must personally delve into an exploration of what quantifiers even are; are they primitive notions; or, could they be expressed as axioms, in terms of some lower thing? This answer to be updated shortly.

[How are quantifiers defined in formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/107772/how-are-quantifiers-defined-in-formal-logic)