# How are quantifiers defined in formal logic?

Tags: quantifiers

Are quantifiers generally taken as a primitive notion, or are there some foundations-for-mathematics systems in which they emerge from lower level notions?

For example, in set theory, "functions" are just sets. Of course, this in itself is food for thought. If we can simply pull out any set of *pairs* from the Von Neumann hierarchy/constructible universe, and *call* it *a function*, I wonder if this begs for further motivation. Might we ask, but *why* did you name *pairs*, and not name some other rule/pattern that can be applied to all sets in the Von Neumman universe?

---

I guess in formal logic, the set of all functions maybe could be written using set comprehension - "the set S of all sets F such that for all sets p in F, the order of p is 2" (unless there are any problems with this; I still am not clear on how set comprehension works in ZFC; I believe there is a restricted form to avoid paradoxes, which is what the Axiom of Choice is used for(?)).

---

The more philosophical aspect of this question is, is there something "inadequate" - it is open to suggestion in what way, what we mean by "inadequate" - about claiming that functions are just sets? One reason why is, in the animated activity that is *thought*, the *interpretation* or *use* of a function in some way, is different from the "static entity" that is a set. For example, consider a "function" whose domain is the same set as the function. A human can "animate" or "operationalize" this function (this "association"). They can know, "whenever someone points to set a, I should associate that with set b" (the elements of the given pair).

I guess a short way to say this is that shown a particular set, a human does not know if the set is a "set" or a "function". In this way of defining sets, it seems like some of the "character" of different mathematical and logical species is missing. It cannot express aspects of what arguably are real, experienced aspects of such ideas as "functions" or "operations".

How does this apply to quantifiers? Are there any logical systems where they are defined as certain types of sets, or types of functions?

I want to speculate on how this could be possible. Functions were abstracted into sets by realizing that the essential core of information, that which could not be pared away, were the elements of the association. A variety of "cognitive metaphors" (which is what we call them now, yet, at various times, were actual human cognitive conceptualizations of what a particular thing *was*) can, and have, been applied to functions: they are like a machine, with inputs out and outputs; they are a rule to be followed; they are a calculation or a computation, or a process or an operation or a transformation; yet, as the definition grew more abstract, it became nothing more than "an association", perhaps the most general term/concept anyone could succeed in thinking of.

From that point of view, what is a "quantifier"? It seems like the ability to select or point out certain elements of a set - none of them, one of them, all of them. Could this be expressed as an "idea", but in sets?

Here is one way I think of this.

Defining all of mathematics in terms of sets, as I said, it to me sometimes has weird properties of what you could call "homonymy". For example, all of what we know as numbers or integers *are actually sets*. The idea "2" is actually the ordinal set 2 (expressible in parentheses by `{{}, {{}}}`).

I guess the lesson I feel I learned is that in this approach, of "constructive set theory" if it can be called that, the way you defined "classes of objects" is merely by stating the set of all such objects. That is where my definition of "function" above came from. Perhaps if we were new or alien to set theory, it would not occur to us that presenting the collection of all of a particular kind of thing amounts to a definition of that thing. We might thing the definition is *something else*, some other thing of some other nature, than the thing itself ("no thing is of itself defined"). And yet, especially as I have studied some induction techniques/algorithms, I have come to see that this is exactly what is often done, and I believe, successfully.

So then... in order to "define" quantifiers... should we specify the set of all situations in which quantification has occurred? Would that be keeping with the spirit of how "functions" have been defined?

I can expand on this more later, but I have some thoughts about how, because, as I said above, the pure set-theoretic definition of a given function arguably does not provide the complete information about that thing that a human knows - a human knows how to "use" the function, the rule encoded in the sets, because they know its a function, and they know how  to disambiguate that given set in situations when its supposed to "represent" something different (like just a regular set). The idea is that because we seem to have allowed - even to require - a degree of "human interpretation", maybe there is more than one way we can define quantifiers, in terms of sets. Maybe, similar to functions, as long as we encode the essential data, we can strip away a lot of what we, personally and cognitively, think quantifiers "mean".

So I'd like to expand on how that could be done, and I'd love some input on how this relates to the ocean of pre-existing thought in set theory and mathematical logic. Thank you.

Comment: If you try to take the set of all and only noncircular sets, Russell's paradox results. So comprehension gives way to separation, which means you can form "the set of all and only elements/subsets with property *P*, from a *previous* set," but if you try to form a set of all sets with a property *P*, like "the set of all inaccessibles" say, you get a (proper) class instead. This is somewhat terminological, ultimately.

Comment: Separation is not absolutely absolute (so to speak), though; and so some of the other axioms might be styled as particular *kinds* of comprehension/separation. We should also consider collection axioms in this vein. As for functions, IIRC von Neumann's set theory has functions as primitively given (c.f. [Church's type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/): "Since properties and relations can be regarded as functions from entities to truth values, the concept of a function is taken as primitive in Church’s type theory").

Comment: [Predicate functor logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_functor_logic) is an attempt to do away with quantification in a logic; for a synoptic look at quantifier theory, see [this SEP artlce](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/). I would surmise that quantification is as "fundamental" as qualification (consider Kant's response to the ontological argument, for example).

Comment: Quantifiers are not defined in formal logic, nor can they be along the suggested lines. Typical set theories are themselves built on predicate logic, so any "definitions" of quantifiers that use set-theoretic concepts will be circular. Those explanations are *interpretations* of quantifiers in [set-theoretic models](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory), not their definitions.

Comment: We can’t do set theory with just logic nor can we do it with just math. I’m thinking of an example of proving two sets are equal, which of course uses the for all quantifier. This allows choosing arbitrary element x (in either set), ergo we don’t need the actual extension of the sets. Hence the proof can be short even if the sets were huge. We can therefore have proofs which handle large and infinite sets, a common want/need. Without logic, we’d be prevented from many proofs of large or infinite sets because we’d have to compare every element or something similarly unwieldy.

Comment: …con’t. As to what quantifiers are, they allow more complex interactions of all and some than Aristotelian logic while avoiding ambiguities in natural language too, they provide an advanced notation. See Prof Michael Potter on Frege for good explanations. Technically A. logic didn’t use all and some specifically but all and some take everything we want from A. Logic with additional benefits.

Comment: You cannot define everything... in set theory we define a relation as a specific set but the binary relation "in" is part of the language itself and it is used to define sets and relations.

Comment: Having said that, see [Generalized Quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/).

Answer (score 2):

In category theory, existential quantifiers can be treated as left adjoints and universal quantifiers - as right adjoints. I'm not sure if this is in any way enlightening. It depends on what kind of definition are you looking for. In any case, there's the [nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantification).

Comment: Would love if you could expand on that if you have time.

Answer (score 1):

Some quantifiers are defined "ostensively," by showing their elementary use. These can also be interdefined, as when we say that existential quantification is a certain negation of universal quantification (or *vice versa*), and then when we have elementary quantifiers, we can go on to construct more complex ones on this basis.

But the overall "category" of quantifiers is somewhat irreducible, or does not admit of noncircularity in its fundamental characterization. Let us suppose, for example, that we proceeded from a general notion of cardinality quantifiers and spoke of minimal and maximal quantifiers ("none"/"zero," "at least one," "absolutely infinitely many," "all"), but so also had intermediary operators like "exactly seven," and so on. By using specific numbers as such in this connection, we would seem to presuppose them in the logical "background" such that a construction of these cardinalities would not longer strictly follow upon the attempt to "reduce" the natural numbers and their transfinite successors to sets. Or, then, these numbers would be used as primitives that are not "logically constructed" but figure *in* further such "construction." The interplay between our set concept and our quantifier concept *per se* would be definitionally circular to some extent, then.